# how can i mix fulltext score with some other value?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to mix the "fulltext's float score" to some other value of my resultset

for instance I want to give relevance to rows that have more user votes... I don't want to sort by user votes, but I want to give "some boost", more visibility, to pages that have a lot of votes.

this is subjective to developer, yes, but the problem is that the "fulltext score" gives no reference point (because the single value is influenced by the entire resultset)

how can I manage this?

thanks... I'm sorry for my english, I hope to have been clear!

scenario:

```
id | keywords         | uservotes
1  | aaaa cccc        |        10
2  | aaaa bbbb cccc   |        20
3  | aaaa cccc        |        0
4  | aaaa bbbb cccc   |        1000 --- this one can have improved visibility
5  | aaaa             |        10

SELECT
        *,
        (
            MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('aaaa')
            +
            /* HERE USERVOTES CALC */
        )
        as score
FROM
        mytable
ORDER BY
        score DESC
```

Comment: Can your provide an example scenario?

Comment: Have you tried simply multiplying the relevance score with the number of votes to see if it's satisfactory?

Comment: yes but what about a third value, for instance a score consisting of fulltextscore + uservotes + pageviews ? thanks

Comment: btw multiplying the score with the votes may be not efficient because there is no affinity with the total score (and the total number of votes in the resultSET)